# iOS app is crashing for some users

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have an application that is in App store. It has been used by more than 5000 users daily. However, I get e-mails from time to time that says the application is not launching. Rebooting the phone or re-installing does not seem to fix the issue. I never had issues with the 3 devices that I test with. Also, I hear lots of good compliments from users.

Recently, I've upgraded to new version and some of the old users had crash as well. Luckily, one of the users sent the following crash log. I can not replicate the issue in either iPhone similator or in my test devices.

Any ideas on how I should debug this? Any information that can be extracted from the crash log below?

With the latest update the app doesn't start. It crashes as soon as it started. Here is the crash log:

```
{"name":"MyApplication","bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1 (11D167)","bundleID":"mycompany.MyApplicationapp","version":"8.0 (8.0)","app_name":"MyApplication"}
Incident Identifier: 95AD7209-51AD-4033-9DA2-C6CC6D91FF3C
CrashReporter Key:   a2bd356c0c7262571660822f9c1adccf7b2527ba
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             MyApplication [396]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/19AABE5D-D58C-4E63-8460-16A5886E4A14/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
Identifier:          mycompany.MyApplicationapp
Version:             8.0 (8.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-04-03 08:46:08.159 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x30adbefe 0x3b270ce2 0x30a16b1c 0x99db6 0x987fe 0x97c36 0x3330fa4e 0x3330f80c 0x33386c38 0x3338559c 0x333850e2 0x3338506a 0x33385002 0x3337d67c 0x33311692 0x33384d54 0x33384824 0x33316610 0x33313dd4 0x3337da4c 0x3337a6e0 0x33374cc4 0x33310c92 0x3330fdf4 0x33374400 0x3597db50 0x3597d73a 0x30aa683a 0x30aa67d6 0x30aa4fa2 0x30a0f7a4 0x30a0f586 0x33373626 0x3336e88c 0x96372 0x3b76eab2)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b8251f0 0x3b812000 + 78320
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88d7b2 0x3b88a000 + 14258
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b7d5ff4 0x3b78c000 + 303092
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac2498a 0x3ac24000 + 2442
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac3b1f4 0x3ac24000 + 94708
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3ac3ad12 0x3ac24000 + 93458
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b270e2a 0x3b26d000 + 15914
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f81a 0x30a07000 + 34842
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f586 0x30a07000 + 34182
9   UIKit                           0x33373626 0x33300000 + 472614
10  UIKit                           0x3336e88c 0x33300000 + 452748
11  MyApplication                           0x00096372 0x92000 + 17266
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b76eab4 0x3b76d000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b812804 0x3b812000 + 2052
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b761050 0x3b759000 + 32848
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b75b2de 0x3b759000 + 8926

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b825c70 0x3b812000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88ac1e 0x3b88a000 + 3102
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aad8 0x3b88a000 + 2776

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b825c70 0x3b812000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88ac1e 0x3b88a000 + 3102
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aad8 0x3b88a000 + 2776

Thread 4:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b277904 0x3b26d000 + 43268
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b275b26 0x3b26d000 + 35622
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b275a7a 0x3b26d000 + 35450
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b2758f0 0x3b26d000 + 35056
4   Foundation                      0x31427b46 0x313f7000 + 199494
5   Foundation                      0x3142f154 0x313f7000 + 229716
6   CoreData                        0x3083f0c2 0x30812000 + 184514
7   CoreData                        0x3085d5dc 0x30812000 + 308700
8   CoreData                        0x308a8d7a 0x30812000 + 617850
9   MyApplication                           0x000bbf38 0x92000 + 171832
10  MyApplication                           0x000bb1be 0x92000 + 168382
11  MyApplication                           0x000bbe26 0x92000 + 171558
12  MyApplication                           0x000c4be4 0x92000 + 207844
13  MyApplication                           0x000c5d7e 0x92000 + 212350
14  MyApplication                           0x000c5b84 0x92000 + 211844
15  Foundation                      0x314c4c1e 0x313f7000 + 842782
16  CoreFoundation                  0x30aa6fe4 0x30a07000 + 655332
17  CoreFoundation                  0x30aa64aa 0x30a07000 + 652458
18  CoreFoundation                  0x30aa4c9a 0x30a07000 + 646298
19  CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f7a4 0x30a07000 + 34724
20  CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f586 0x30a07000 + 34182
21  Foundation                      0x31402492 0x313f7000 + 46226
22  Foundation                      0x31453254 0x313f7000 + 377428
23  MyApplication                           0x000b8d70 0x92000 + 159088
24  Foundation                      0x314c4a0a 0x313f7000 + 842250
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c956 0x3b88a000 + 10582
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c8c6 0x3b88a000 + 10438
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aae4 0x3b88a000 + 2788

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b825c70 0x3b812000 + 81008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88ac1e 0x3b88a000 + 3102
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aad8 0x3b88a000 + 2776

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b812a50 0x3b812000 + 2640
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b812848 0x3b812000 + 2120
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30aa661c 0x30a07000 + 652828
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30aa4d3c 0x30a07000 + 646460
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f7a4 0x30a07000 + 34724
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f586 0x30a07000 + 34182
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2fa7445e 0x2fa63000 + 70750
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2fa688fc 0x2fa63000 + 22780
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c956 0x3b88a000 + 10582
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c8c6 0x3b88a000 + 10438
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aae4 0x3b88a000 + 2788

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b81568c 0x3b812000 + 13964
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3b79a142 0x3b78c000 + 57666
2   CFNetwork                       0x30775764 0x30697000 + 911204
3   CFNetwork                       0x306cc120 0x30697000 + 217376
4   CFNetwork                       0x306d3896 0x30697000 + 247958
5   CFNetwork                       0x306d3836 0x30697000 + 247862
6   CFNetwork                       0x30777166 0x30697000 + 917862
7   CFNetwork                       0x30778cd8 0x30697000 + 924888
8   CFNetwork                       0x3076e2f8 0x30697000 + 881400
9   CFNetwork                       0x3073e2fc 0x30697000 + 684796
10  CFNetwork                       0x3073fa46 0x30697000 + 690758
11  CFNetwork                       0x30715540 0x30697000 + 517440
12  CFNetwork                       0x306d36be 0x30697000 + 247486
13  CFNetwork                       0x3071015e 0x30697000 + 495966
14  CFNetwork                       0x30699c08 0x30697000 + 11272
15  Foundation                      0x3146d63e 0x313f7000 + 484926
16  MyApplication                           0x000a7d6e 0x92000 + 89454
17  Foundation                      0x314c4a0a 0x313f7000 + 842250
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c956 0x3b88a000 + 10582
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c8c6 0x3b88a000 + 10438
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aae4 0x3b88a000 + 2788

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b812a50 0x3b812000 + 2640
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b812848 0x3b812000 + 2120
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30aa661c 0x30a07000 + 652828
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30aa4d3c 0x30a07000 + 646460
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f7a4 0x30a07000 + 34724
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30a0f586 0x30a07000 + 34182
6   Foundation                      0x3144f23c 0x313f7000 + 361020
7   Foundation                      0x314c4a0a 0x313f7000 + 842250
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c956 0x3b88a000 + 10582
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88c8c6 0x3b88a000 + 10438
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b88aae4 0x3b88a000 + 2788

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3d77f18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d71a50
    r8: 0x14e9df60    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x33950037     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d71a44      lr: 0x3b88d7b7      pc: 0x3b8251f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0x92000 - 0xd5fff MyApplication armv7s  <8ed789cc71d33112b984055644b660b6> /var/mobile/Applications/19AABE5D-D58C-4E63-8460-16A5886E4A14/MyApplication.app/MyApplication
0x2be37000 - 0x2be5afff dyld armv7s  <4d05d388718832c99cdd4e74aeb07d51> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2f64c000 - 0x2f650fff AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7s  <5a4056e3e7d63bbf9cd9789ce2f1b319> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2f74d000 - 0x2f836fff RawCamera armv7s  <f70ac6362c49391bb9c10441847cdabd> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x2f960000 - 0x2fa62fff AVFoundation armv7s  <c88b12b244d13bbd9a8ab681956234e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2fa63000 - 0x2fa8bfff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7s  <b92283f0007834c7a52635881be94ab7> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2fa8c000 - 0x2fa8cfff Accelerate armv7s  <58ca068138d93e988a34a0c8c34b0b11> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2fa96000 - 0x2fc63fff vImage armv7s  <9923548d8ed23bb1b1020130b5d38dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2fc64000 - 0x2fd46fff libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <48f7680a8fd83251ad8415bb090408c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2fd47000 - 0x2fffffff libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <2547383dc88d3329827b4d76768915ee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x30000000 - 0x3006efff libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <83036da6f5d9308bb5fad06b2d29bac9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3006f000 - 0x30081fff libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <addc52a9647f3269965a750366ebed70> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x30082000 - 0x30082fff vecLib armv7s  <4a647b20c3f03490aae530226350a4cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30083000 - 0x300a3fff Accounts armv7s  <73b0639b81fe30d5b2b13628d3df2273> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x300a5000 - 0x3010cfff AddressBook armv7s  <e0051f44c0d0377da85049ff86fbc890> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30224000 - 0x30235fff AssetsLibrary armv7s  <372ff89a2ede36aa85ce562f3e513f07> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
0x3037a000 - 0x30696fff AudioToolbox armv7s  <42ef392f2082317cbd3857838ab97aaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30697000 - 0x3079dfff CFNetwork armv7s  <92222e5708af3145bb068d8f3b481572> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3079e000 - 0x307f9fff CoreAudio armv7s  <34a6461e9ad3380ea9e0405f81aad500> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x307fa000 - 0x30811fff CoreBluetooth armv7s  <0e672bb563ea3c2fb0c6ae0070d00efb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x30812000 - 0x30a06fff CoreData armv7s  <23650924fc293fdf994419f6894720a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30a07000 - 0x30b4aff0 CoreFoundation armv7s  <e0dda373f78f367c9f64627dc8e01eb0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30b4b000 - 0x30c6ffff CoreGraphics armv7s  <182ccc3a111d360eb5c1e58b4289afb3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30c71000 - 0x30cacfff libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7s  <1d9c402cc18433db9a72d349876b2fea> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x30cae000 - 0x30cb8fff libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7s  <1efb72c2985332c485d07c5a3784f93b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
0x30e9d000 - 0x30eb7fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7s  <23b82f0d28e238938519439e243ae7a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30eb8000 - 0x30f91fff CoreImage armv7s  <1eedb55ace133e10bb629fa881c45542> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x30f92000 - 0x30fe1fff CoreLocation armv7s  <5d78705a46ab313fa21f1d5ed2f0ce3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x31019000 - 0x31094fff CoreMedia armv7s  <2f8fa07e557f3b29b932d31865d2121a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31095000 - 0x3113dfff CoreMotion armv7s  <bd402a711091322bb2284be34283973f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x3113e000 - 0x31196fff CoreTelephony armv7s  <711db5ac808937b09143f43f11f06422> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31197000 - 0x31227fff CoreText armv7s  <43e84c5a90fc36a984363965f2d8029b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x31228000 - 0x31237fff CoreVideo armv7s  <b114a9e05c08366b8735a2911defa97b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x313f7000 - 0x315e1fff Foundation armv7s  <b75ca4f9d9b739ef9b16e482db277849> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x317c3000 - 0x31819fff IOKit armv7s  <8905cade40f43b668931f86c5832abc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3181a000 - 0x31a2afff ImageIO armv7s  <3234150da2d13945a33c98335e53db80> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31a2b000 - 0x31c76fff JavaScriptCore armv7s  <2192c163793b3e04a8f9917eda045d8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31c77000 - 0x31d26fff MapKit armv7s  <c4067ff919c537419f29fe6288d9792d> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x31d27000 - 0x31d2bfff MediaAccessibility armv7s  <c87f228e5b18380d837ed901196705c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x31f2a000 - 0x32230fff MediaToolbox armv7s  <84b2b485897333008869c65c1e033d5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x322dd000 - 0x32340fff MobileCoreServices armv7s  <1a736ebbc93431c8943cdd93a0a0fdcb> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x32d88000 - 0x32d90fff OpenGLES armv7s  <1c3e551d0a923b86940ad36a6e682463> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32d92000 - 0x32d92fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <ba661b77360f360b88c3163a02538376> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x32d97000 - 0x32d9afff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <38ff1c7f12f83f8bac062e8daf9d4c10> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x32d9b000 - 0x32da2fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <2406a4e5c5b437dbb0a3553655ac4951> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32da3000 - 0x32de3fff libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <7d912d8e3a453456a6e2d806b59aa448> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32f7b000 - 0x330c2fff QuartzCore armv7s  <741ee0338b1235aab1550f91a3956041> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3311c000 - 0x3315efff Security armv7s  <289005dd72603957923ec376a37fa16f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3315f000 - 0x331d6fff Social armv7s  <44855abfc74336e5a1432e6145405c15> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
0x332ae000 - 0x332fdfff SystemConfiguration armv7s  <82758c34b29a333bbdfe73e78361e0e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x33300000 - 0x33a73fff UIKit armv7s  <f725ad0982673286911bff834295ec99> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33a74000 - 0x33ac2fff VideoToolbox armv7s  <aef48ac94d1030e79385660b45085b99> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33d3b000 - 0x33d44fff AOSNotification armv7s  <a5c6a910b5733c1887af0e763878957c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/AOSNotification
0x33daa000 - 0x33df4fff AccessibilityUtilities armv7s  <2f39b6e781ab3f6993dd2599b8bc9372> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities
0x33e6a000 - 0x33e6efff AggregateDictionary armv7s  <b4e58fe6256136749b7d54bf07bcbc51> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34161000 - 0x34492fff Altitude armv7s  <18e7637a826631a99d2c6c6e145c7271> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
0x344ca000 - 0x34508fff AppSupport armv7s  <0cb23d5c42d530cfa7e43605cf368293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34509000 - 0x34540fff AppleAccount armv7s  <736438792a0d3884a745f2fe1e4d8582> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x345ee000 - 0x345fefff ApplePushService armv7s  <3f89365747c33bcfa22a4d3009cd1715> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x345ff000 - 0x34605fff AppleSRP armv7s  <e1db5ed3b8e034ce94f260077c96cea8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
0x34632000 - 0x3463efff AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <05cf849c0bab37698f93ce58e0cabe0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34688000 - 0x3468bfff BTLEAudioController armv7s  <f420608b2d7538bb88491b34501a36f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
0x3468c000 - 0x346b1fff BackBoardServices armv7s  <eef3e744484a386ca351b8feb000eb37> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x346b4000 - 0x346b9fff BluetoothManager armv7s  <9d86b542e884374f9845e9a53139abd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x346ba000 - 0x346defff Bom armv7s  <af79573fee7d364da59eed3fabe2f645> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3477f000 - 0x34787fff CaptiveNetwork armv7s  <9825d6ad32163fcd8f2f56dbf274de62> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x34788000 - 0x34864fff Celestial armv7s  <6fcb14a0193e336a938d7f68c01bc2c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34871000 - 0x34876fff CertUI armv7s  <68968485501f35c09203bd9e045bbcd0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x34942000 - 0x34962fff ChunkingLibrary armv7s  <a8a788dadd083a78b00f3aed5bdc9215> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x349b3000 - 0x349befff CommonUtilities armv7s  <f477748e4ac03e91b3a2769b59dc0dc0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x349bf000 - 0x349c3fff CommunicationsFilter armv7s  <87e7685b12ac375aa482a7a31cd28517> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
0x34a54000 - 0x34a56fff ConstantClasses armv7s  <aab583ee29ff3ed7a9ad2bddfbc9bcde> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x34a96000 - 0x34a98fff CoreAUC armv7s  <77474784f35a35718fa5c6bd358ec659> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
0x34b3a000 - 0x34c39fff CoreMediaStream armv7s  <5cd75f6b32eb3dd68f04251e9a9910ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x34d4c000 - 0x34d4dfff CoreSurface armv7s  <12e5cc9dcc093836ad0f36d8fc311158> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34d4e000 - 0x34db4fff CoreSymbolication armv7s  <c7e97a3ec72b325592f1c9cc26408614> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/CoreSymbolication
0x34df4000 - 0x34e50fff CoreUI armv7s  <3fdd5b6ee0b03774a8a67554e8a3c3ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x34e51000 - 0x34ea5fff CoreUtils armv7s  <2cd95e7adf393d0e9656dcaee71b8298> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
0x34ea6000 - 0x34eabfff CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <1945ce446ee632278fd2b45bec71ef4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35077000 - 0x3508dfff DataAccessExpress armv7s  <d267039af5923039bb15d53806a16edc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x350c8000 - 0x350ccfff DataMigration armv7s  <24479dd9d49a354da98e6a0ce861558b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x350d1000 - 0x350d2fff DiagnosticLogCollection armv7s  <92f04186ee463c60a309eb847f65466e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
0x350d3000 - 0x350ecfff DictionaryServices armv7s  <b32f1de0807532e2944c9365d543b542> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3510b000 - 0x35128fff EAP8021X armv7s  <fe7ffb1fa4543f81bebfc2d100002cc2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35131000 - 0x3513cfff ExFAT armv7s  <a50c8c49cc703ad59b3caff9dfe105e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExFAT.framework/ExFAT
0x35151000 - 0x3517bfff FTServices armv7s  <5989eb9b68a132db848c18787b74a8ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3517c000 - 0x35597fff FaceCore armv7s  <72642f324b7639faa8206f00a953a573> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x357b9000 - 0x357c5fff GenerationalStorage armv7s  <516e7f1921473c9f9eb6e96028db121a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x357c6000 - 0x35972fff GeoServices armv7s  <1d0e1ac52cc636e2a6ff9d130bc9108d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x35973000 - 0x35989fff GraphicsServices armv7s  <3b6c1bed029a36809c005aded6358ae2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x35b13000 - 0x35b47fff IDS armv7s  <ec16c2518f6f323390cc725022979078> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
0x35bb7000 - 0x35bc8fff IDSFoundation armv7s  <aa2a898449b5350f85993c2f8737ce6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
0x35d3b000 - 0x35d95fff IMFoundation armv7s  <1fe1f17117fd346e872606e1fbaf958f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x35d9f000 - 0x35da6fff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <0d8975886a1c35ebaa01fbf02f749357> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35da7000 - 0x35dacfff IOSurface armv7s  <fa838c3cfdee37e68b9ec83283fc4ad2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35e1e000 - 0x35e2afff Librarian armv7s  <5a7a4cc07a8832eaabe06e90c51f6c88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x35e65000 - 0x35ea2fff MMCS armv7s  <6364dddaf21436edb79cf2cc5f6bfc08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x35eab000 - 0x35eb6fff MailServices armv7s  <87e489916f793167912630e25d52981d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x35eea000 - 0x35f65fff ManagedConfiguration armv7s  <ff4aa3ba73fa3c6295d84a663b7230ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x35f66000 - 0x35f67fff Marco armv7s  <a6d37d7ca6de35abbe32371d5713347c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x35f68000 - 0x35fe1fff MediaControlSender armv7s  <ecca229a940e30c0b98d635758a10433> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x36020000 - 0x3602dfff MediaRemote armv7s  <9d9e2ea66c0836ab886b38beb1b05532> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x3602e000 - 0x36046fff MediaStream armv7s  <4240fd93479530b98e0c08adf1f6bb0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x36184000 - 0x36186fff MessageSupport armv7s  <8bfa1bdecbeb39b6b9c0dee8ebc14469> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x36192000 - 0x3619efff MobileAsset armv7s  <6813f72ce0593cfea861addfd1357fac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x361c2000 - 0x361cafff MobileBluetooth armv7s  <8dd3363b6e2330d9b0eb427f5010b199> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x361e5000 - 0x361e8fff MobileInstallation armv7s  <7e644fec475d31c2bde3c0a9249ea3c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x361e9000 - 0x361f3fff MobileKeyBag armv7s  <849c15afb1a8346994fe6673710fa23b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3621b000 - 0x3621efff MobileSystemServices armv7s  <1bc1a98c34d5398ca9ff7d2a6cd65243> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x3623d000 - 0x36248fff MobileWiFi armv7s  <6f236a63a5a831a9ab224cae7ba30ed6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x364e4000 - 0x364e9fff Netrb armv7s  <11576949484a3405881d436920cf495c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x364ea000 - 0x364effff NetworkStatistics armv7s  <04f1b60537e03715934f8cdbb2992fbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x36515000 - 0x36517fff OAuth armv7s  <e5d7ef5ec520310187365df875a549ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x36c6e000 - 0x36ca9fff OpenCL armv7s  <b6fbdfb3287d3fbfb5286db2871e20f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3724f000 - 0x37276fff PersistentConnection armv7s  <199be1a72cf136e38f3e97f918225ac3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x373c3000 - 0x3753cfff PhotoLibraryServices armv7s  <e65564173ae9360fb16a812c39d587b1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
0x37692000 - 0x376c5fff PhysicsKit armv7s  <eabb43d582b434e7a07113dc75526237> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x376c6000 - 0x376c9fff PowerLog armv7s  <e6467b6007a03c1eadec925dd5fead89> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x377bc000 - 0x377f3fff PrintKit armv7s  <07cdb8fa73f638878da43cb85ecc6525> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x377f7000 - 0x3787dfff ProofReader armv7s  <c51b02fd95b5374a92d5f442914fd833> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x3787e000 - 0x37888fff ProtocolBuffer armv7s  <e51109e38b5e3229941c644bd3c1fda0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x378ba000 - 0x3792efff Quagga armv7s  <14d6711448dd35da93958349e88c67bb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x37b01000 - 0x37b20fff ScreenReaderCore armv7s  <0abd423f7abd394c91dacd38391c024d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReaderCore.framework/ScreenReaderCore
0x37c21000 - 0x37c36fff SpringBoardServices armv7s  <c57673fe5697361292f6d98f0e42b43a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x37e78000 - 0x37f9afff StoreServices armv7s  <95cccb75d8393b4ba47843d1e4c4d5bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3804a000 - 0x3804cfff TCC armv7s  <c954ee084fc138cd9e1efd673fcc1db6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x380a0000 - 0x380c1fff TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <89a81f2b2d00390f94886d091df8c370> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x3844c000 - 0x3847ffff TextInput armv7s  <d99157b55d1c36ad80c417de08f1f5a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x38480000 - 0x38676fff TextToSpeech armv7s  <646740317d2937489b630b5263086d07> 
some more libraries (removed due to space body text size limitation).
```

**Edit**: 
Here is the symbolicated code:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
 21 0   CoreFoundation                      0x30adbefe __exceptionPreprocess + 126
 22 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b270ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
 23 2   CoreFoundation                      0x30a16b1c -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:] + 456
```

Works fine in xcode debugging.

Comment: Step one: Symbolicate. If you don't know what that means, google it...

Comment: We need a symbolicated trace to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the sybolicated trace:        Last Exception Backtrace:
 21 0   CoreFoundation                      0x30adbefe __exceptionPreprocess + 126
 22 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b270ce2 objc_exception_throw + 34
 23 2   CoreFoundation                      0x30a16b1c -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:] + 456    In my Xcode, the NSArray is not nil and elements are replaced with new strings. I dont see how that would cause an exception.

Comment: for some reason my array should be empty.. I will focus on that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to get far with only those details, however:

```
[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]
```

There are only two possible things that can go wrong:

- the index is invalid, it's less than 0 or greater than the array's length
- the object being inserted is nil or points to a location in RAM that doesn't contain an object

Find all the places where you modify an array during the app launch process, and put if statements in place to check the index and object, then pop up an error message to the user. Hopefully some of them will email back to you.

Also, the person who emailed you a crash report... you might want to ask for their device id and send them an ad-hoc beta release of your app for testing.

If the issue is "the object is a location in RAM that doesn't contain an object"... then you could have a long fight ahead of you, because that probably means a memory corruption issue somewhere else in your code. Try turning ARC on, if it isn't already. Try using the Product -> Analyse menu item in Xcode, and fix any warnings that come up.

Comment: Thanks. ARC is enabled. Xcode Analyse does not return any warning.

Comment: Another possibility is that the array pointer itself points to a deallocated object or location that doesn't contain an object. A memory trashing bug can also cause this sort of problem. Finally, make sure you don't have any "assign" properties that should be "strong".

Comment: @EricS I think if it shows `__NSArrayM` in the stack trace then there must be an `NSMutableArray` at the memory location. So it can't be that.

Comment: Ok. I have an NSMutableArray *firstArray which is defined as readonly (@property (readonly, readonly) NSMutableArray *firstArray). This is initialized when the object is created. Then, I copy it to another array (@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *secondArray) as self.secondArray = obj.firstArray; and replace the entries in secondArray; I guess that is the issue. However, how come it works in almost all of the cases and fails only for some very small number of users?

Comment: @Mikrasya `self.secondArray = obj.firstArray;` does not make a copy, you still only have one array. To make a copy you have to do `self.secondArray = obj.firstArray.mutableCopy;`. Please post all your code where you work with both arrays. It sounds like we have found where the bug is, but I need to see the code to help you fix it.

Comment: Accepting this as the correct answer. The issue turned out to be related to location, I had localization strings for 3 languages that I support. It is still a misery how it worked in previous version. The following helped alot with debugging 1) symbolicate, 2) ad-hoc distribution to the person who send me the crash report. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: "It is still a misery how it worked in previous version." That happens to me all the time.